# How to pass a success function as parameter?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is it possible to pass a function as parameter to the success function name?

```
function processFunction(successFunction){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
      url: `URL`,
      method: 'GET',
      scope: this,
      success: 'successFunction',
      failure: 'requestFailure',
    });
}
```

I tried this above but it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't quote the function. Then it's a string, not a function.

Comment: @Barmar, you can in ExtJS. It can also be this.successFunction(). That's inside a controller

Comment: But probably not a local variable, only a global function name.

Comment: Another possibility would be to set the scope to your controller. An example can be found here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cri